# Cionnection Refused when running Python script

Tags: python

I am running the following python script within Oracle Virtualbox running Kali Linux and keep getting connection refused.

`client.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
#client.py

import socket

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8080

client.connect((host, port)) # Connect to our client
msg = client.recv(1024)
client.close()

print (msg.decode('ascii'))
```

```sh
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/Downloads]
└─$ python3 client.py  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Downloads/client.py", line 10, in <module>
    client.connect((host, port)) # Connect to our client
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: What's your question? You can [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask].

Comment: you should have server and client code on two separate threads / process or computers.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this, the code is correct but I have not created a listner on port 8080.

Create a new python file name server.py and ran it.

Then ran my client.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#server.py

import socket 

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 8080
     
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((host,port))
server.listen(2)
print('Server is listening for incoming connections')
     
while True:
    conn,addr = server.accept()
    print("Connection Received from %s" % str(addr))
    msg = 'Connection Established'+ "\r\n"
    conn.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
    conn.close()
```